# beginner question about python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, postgresql, multicore

I have a number of records in the database I want to process. Basically, I want to run several regex substitution over tokens of the text string rows and at the end, and write them back to the database.

I wish to know whether does multiprocessing speeds up the time required to do such tasks. 
I did a

> multiprocessing.cpu_count

and it returns 8. I have tried something like

```
process = []
for i in range(4):
    if i == 3:
        limit = resultsSize - (3 * division)
    else:
        limit = division

    #limit and offset indicates the subset of records the function would fetch in the db
    p = Process(target=sub_table.processR,args=(limit,offset,i,))
    p.start()
    process.append(p)
    offset += division + 1

for po in process:
    po.join()
```

but apparently, the time taken is higher than the time required to run a single thread. Why is this so? Can someone please enlighten is this a suitable case or what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you really testing it with 4 iterations? Spawning each process is going to take time. Also, postgresql will only use one cpu per connection. So it may be just queuing 4 queries and running them sequentially. Also, splitting up the work may not beneficial depending on the overhead of starting up each query. Also, there a things that are just dependent on your system such a the background processes and what hardware you are running.

Comment: @nate, Im testing it with 4. I think i'm using 1 connection per process though..

Comment: Check the server log and the times it ran each query. There is a difference between a cursor and connection. Also, it will only help if the query is actually cpu bound e.g. your total_cpu monitor is 100% / cpu_num. So you want your test query to be pretty intensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of questions:

1. In your `processR` function, does it slurp a large number of records from the database at one time, or is it fetching 1 row at a time?  (Each row fetch will be very costly, performance wise.)
2. It may not work for your specific application, but since you are processing "everything", using database will likely be slower than a flat file.  Databases are optimised for logical queries, not seqential processing.  In your case, can you export the whole table column to a CSV file, process it, and then re-import the results?

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: Hey @nonot1, in my processR function i read couple of thousands of records at one go into a variable, after processing a record i did sequential updates one record at a time but did not commit the operation till all the updates are done. is there database access even though no committing was done?

Comment: @goh By keeping the transaction open, the database is forced to keep an "undo/redo" log of all actions going on at that time.  This is a huge performance hit.  Since your `proccessR` functions will never see the same data, if you must use a DB, explicitly avoid opening a transaction. (Put a "process guid" and time stamp on the records from each `proccessR` so you can recover from a crash if needed. )

Answer (score 5):

> Why is this so?
>
> Can someone please enlighten in what cases does multiprocessing gives better performances?

Here's one trick.

Multiprocessing only helps when your bottleneck is a resource that's **not** shared.

A shared resource (like a database) will be pulled in 8 different directions, which has little real benefit.

To find a non-shared resource, you must have independent objects.  Like a list that's already in memory.

If you want to work from a database, you need to get 8 things started which then do no more database work.  So, a central query that distributes work to separate processors can sometimes be beneficial.

Or 8 different files.  Note that the file system -- as  a whole -- is a shared resource and some kinds of file access are involve sharing something like a disk drive or a directory.

Or a pipeline of 8 smaller steps.  The standard unix pipeline trick `query | process1 | process2 | process3 >file` works better than almost anything else because each stage in the pipeline is completely independent.

Here's the other trick.

Your computer system (OS, devices, database, network, etc.) is so complex that simplistic theories won't explain performance at all.  You need to (a) take several measurements and (b) try several different algorithms until you understand all the degrees of freedom.

A question like "Can someone please enlighten in what cases does multiprocessing gives better performances?" doesn't have a simple answer.

In order to have a simple answer, you'd need a much, much simpler operating system.  Fewer devices.  No database and no network, for example.  Since your OS is complex, there's no simple answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In general, multicpu or multicore processing help most when your problem is CPU bound (i.e., spends most of its time with the CPU running as fast as it can).

From your description, you have an IO bound problem: It takes forever to get data from disk to the CPU (which is idle) and then the CPU operation is very fast (because it is so simple).

Thus, accelerating the CPU operation does not make a very big difference overall.